# Pip command not found. Issues with Path

Tags: python, pip

I am new to python and terminal so I apologize in advance and thank you for your time. I installed python as well as homebrew. I was trying to do

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

and received

```
Password:
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

I have spent most of the day looking up answers to fixing this issue but I feel as though I am just muddying up my directories. I am at a point where it might be better to just erase/uninstall anything python related and reinstall correctly.

when I look up the path there are many different versions of python in different directories

```
~$ echo $PATH   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Any advice on how to fix this issue/troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated. Or a way to recursively uninstall/erase python so that I can start fresh if this would be easier. Thank You

Comment: Always use `python3 -m pip` to avoid accidentally mixing versions. You can use `python3 -m ensurepip` to bootstrap.

Comment: adding the 3 helped thanks

Answer (score 6):

On xcode8.3 you need to use either `pip2` or `pip3` so for example; `pip3 install flask`

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands:

```
python -m ensurepip
python -m pip install apache-airflow
```